# Set input class if two variables are equal with VueJS

Tags: css, vue.js, vuex

I'd like my `<input>` class to be set to `saved` when its value `$event.target.value` is equal to my **Vuex** state variable `this.$store.state.company.name`.

How should I set it ?

Answer (score 1):

Check out [Class and Style Bindings](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/class-and-style.html#Binding-HTML-Classes) in the docs, you could bind `saved` class to a computed property which checks if the input equals Vuex state variable, here is an example:

```js
new Vue({
    el:"#app",
  data: {
    inputData : '',
  },
  computed: {
    validated(){
        // Here we should compare data from vuex and the user input
        return this.inputData == "mohd"
    }
  }
})
```

```css
.saved {
  border: 1px green solid;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.5.13/dist/vue.min.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <label> write mohd to validate it</label> 
  <input type="text" :class="{saved: validated}" v-model="inputData">
</div>
```

Comment: I don't think I can do it with data: and computed: because my inputs are created dynamically according to a Vuex object.

Answer (score 0):

**InputSave.vue**

```
<template>
  <input type="text" v-model="myInput" :disabled="isEqual" :class="isEqual ? 'saved" : ''" />
</template>

<script>
import { mapGetters } from 'vuex'

  export default {
    data() {
      myInput: ''
    },

    methods: {
      ...mapGetters
    },

    computed: {
      isEqual: function() {
        return this.myInput === this.myGgetter
      }
    }
  }
</script>
```

Comment: How can I put myInput dynamically in data() ? Or is there another way to access its value from isEqual ?

Comment: myInput is already dynamic. Just try this code.
If you want to check your myInput, just add {{ myInput }} below <input> tag.
Do not forget to wrap this code into root tag.

Comment: I can't set `v-model="myInput"` because I already have `:value="this.$store.state.company.name"`.

Comment: data() {
      myInput: this.myGetter // this.$store.state.company.name
    }

Answer (score 0):

Solved here : https://jsfiddle.net/9a9cvu7b/10/ , in fact you can solve it with plain JavaScript.

Just instanciate the `check` method on all your dynamics generated inputs attached to event `@input` (who is thrown each time the input value change on keyup)

```
<div id="app">
    <input 
        type="text" 
        @input="check">
</div>
```

---

```
const app = new Vue({
    el:'#app',
    data() {
        return {
            wordToCheck: 'toto'
        }
    },

    methods: {

        check(event) {
            const input = event.target;

             // replace this.wordToCheck by this.$store.state.company.name
            if(input.value === this.wordToCheck) {
                input.classList.add("saved")
            } else {
                input.classList.remove("saved")
            }
        }
     }
})
```